# how to make local machine to assume IAM role

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

**What I have**

1. an IAM user
2. an IAM role with s3,sqs permissions
3. a spring-boot rest
4. web service utilising aws resources  service authenticating aws
   role-based ( no keys provided )

**What I want**

1. run the application locally
2. some way to make the local machine to assume desired IAM role

**Aws Resource initialisation**

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper())
                .withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION)
                .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
                .build();

AmazonSQS amazonSQSClient = amazonSQSClient = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper())
                .withRegion(Region.getRegion(regions).getName())
                .build();
```

now when I run application and make calls 
obviously the AWS access is denied

I dint find any tutorial , where I can make certain configs on local machine and assume the desired role on local machine.

Comment: I'm a Python person, not Java, but the same general approach should work. I'd put the IAM User credentials in the local credentials file (easiest is via the AWS CLI `aws configure` command). Then, call `AssumeRole()` with no credentials (since they will be obtained from the credentials file). This will then return a set of temporary credentials that can be used to create a `Session` for use with creating clients. Take a look at the code sample on: [Delegating API Access to AWS Services Using IAM Roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/delegating-api-access-to-aws-services-using-iam-roles/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein : looks like a full answer rather than a mere comment , thanks , let me try

Answer (score 2):

We have had this issue quite a lot. But your case is simpler since you're using the `DefaultCredentialProviderChain`. The chain searches for credentials in environment, and then IAM (in that order I think).

My suggestion would be to forget about mocking IAM, mock the services instead. Set some dummy credentials in the environment so that the provider chain uses those instead of trying to use IAM.

For S3: https://github.com/adobe/S3Mock

For SQS: https://github.com/MeteoGroup/sqsmock

Now if you're absolutely determined to mock IAM, Check out this: https://github.com/NYTimes/mock-ec2-metadata

Be warned, the setup for that is not worth what you get out of it. YMMV

You may also be interested in: https://github.com/localstack/localstack

But I haven't used that one (yet).

EDIT: Why is mocking IAM hard? Because the iam credentials come from the metadata endpoint, which is `http://169.254.168.254`. So to mock IAM, you have to mock the metadata endpoint. And that usually involves an `iptables` hack of some sort.

Comment: actually i added default provider chain so that i can at least test application by providing keys , but i wanna use 'EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper' , let me edit the question

Comment: The links and pointers i provided in my answer should point you the right way on how to mock IAM. But my advice remains to not do that and use mock credentials for local environment instead.